# Win32 SetupComm function throwing media is write protected error

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I am writing a program in C++ to read and write from a serial port.

One issue that I have not been able to fix is, after calling SetupComm it fails.

Using `GetLastError()` tells me that it was error `0x00000013`, "The media is write-protected" is the definition of that error code.

Googling what that means has lead me nowhere in terms of programming. I keep finding results pointing to blogs over harddrives refusing to let the user write and stuff like that. None have been programming based results.

One additional, interesting piece of information, is despite `SetupComm` failing I can still successfully write to the serial port. I just can't read from it.

Here is the code I have for opening the connection, up until I call `SetupComm`:

```
string s = "com1";
LPCSTR port = s.c_str();
DWORD dwDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
DWORD dwShareMode = 0;
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = NULL;
DWORD dwCreationDistribution = OPEN_EXISTING;
DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes = FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;
HANDLE hTemplateFile = NULL;

handle = CreateFile(port, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDistribution, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
bufferSizeReceive = 16;
bufferSizeTransmit = 16;

BOOL success = SetupComm(handle, bufferSizeReceive, bufferSizeTransmit);
```

Comment: Please show the code that opens the port.

Comment: Added the code up until I call SetupComm

Comment: Can we assume that immediately after the code you showed you have `if (!success) cout << GetLastError() << endl;` (or something like it) and not any other API calls between, and that is how you're getting the error code 0x13? (Or that you're stepping through in the debugger, and manually doing the same thing)

Comment: And where is the code that makes sure `CreateFile()` is not failing to open the serial port before calling `SetupComm()` to configure it?

Comment: Yes, immediately after the SetupComm I check if success is true. If it is, I continue, if not, I get the last error code to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I suppose I do not check if the handle fails, however I do know the handle works since I am able to write to the port (and SetupComm is not throwing error 6, which would be invalid handle. It did that before when I realized I was calling CreateFile incorrectly before).